# client side caching of file served by php via readfile()

Tags: php, apache, caching, readfile

I am using a php script (server is apache) to serve Pdf files to authenticated users. The files are stored outside the web root. Once the authentication is done I use readfile() to send the data over.

As these files can get big I would like for the client browsers to cache them locally in order to save bandwidth.

I have set some headers to that effect, but right now it seems to only work in safari, not in firefox nor chrome.

Here is my script:

```
<?php

if(!defined('BASE_URI')){
    require_once('../includes/config.inc.php');
    require_once('../includes/utils.inc.php');
    trigger_error("unauthorized direct module access");
    print_json_error("something went wrong, we are working on it...");
    exit();
}

require_once('../includes/utils.inc.php');
require_once(DB);

$auth = new \Delight\Auth\Auth($conn);

if (!$auth->isLoggedIn()) {
    trigger_error("NOT LOGGED IN");
    print_json_error("NOT LOGGED IN");
    exit;
}

if (!$auth->hasRole(\Delight\Auth\Role::SUPER_ADMIN)){
    trigger_error("WRONG CREDENTIALS");
    print_json_error("WRONG CREDENTIALS");
    exit;
}

if(getenv('REQUEST_METHOD') == 'GET'){

    
    if(!isset($_GET['mime']) || !isset($_GET['path'])){

        trigger_error("wrong input: ".$_GET);
        print_json_error("wrong input");
        exit();
    }

    $filepath = '../restricted/'.$_GET['path'];
    $path = getcwd().$filepath;
    $pathdir = dirname($path);
    $checkPath = realpath(pathinfo($path)['dirname']);

    if(strpos($pathdir, $checkPath) !== 0 || strpos($pathdir, $checkPath) === false) { 
        trigger_error("INVALID GET PATH: ".$checkPath." ".$pathdir);
        print_json_error("INVALID GET PATH");
        exit;
    }

    if($_GET['mime'] == 'pdf'){
        header('Content-type: application/pdf');
        header("Content-type: application/octet-stream");
        header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=$filepath");
        
        $seconds_to_cache = 360000;
        $ts = gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s", time() + $seconds_to_cache) . " GMT";
        header("Expires: $ts");
        header("Pragma: cache");
        header("Cache-Control: max-age=$seconds_to_cache, immutable");
        
        
        ob_end_flush();
        readfile($filepath);
        exit();
    } else {
        trigger_error("UNSUPPORTED FILE TYPE: ".$_GET['mime']);
        print_json_error("UNSUPPORTED FILE TYPE");
        exit();
    }

}

trigger_error("INVALID REQUEST");
print_json_error("INVALID REQUEST");
exit();

?>
```

And the response headers I get:

```
HTTP/2 200 OK
content-type: application/octet-stream
date: Thu, 28 Jul 2022 13:21:35 GMT
server: Apache
x-frame-options: sameorigin
x-content-type-options: nosniff
content-disposition: attachment; filename=[..]
expires: Mon, 01 Aug 2022 17:21:35 GMT
pragma: cache
cache-control: max-age=360000, immutable
X-Firefox-Spdy: h2
```

Did I miss something?

Comment: When you go to that URL to download the document what headers are being passed to the browser? Can you see the headers you expect in the inspectors network tab?

Answer (score 0):

I realized I was only reloading big files when small files were caching correctly.

In firefox, it turned out the browser.cache.disk.max_entry_size in about:config was smaller than that of the file I was testing.

Changing the max cache size fixed it.